# django cms "Request Approval" not working

Tags: django, django-cms

I am trying to figure out whether this is a global error or something just on my system.

I have two sets of users - one admin - one content publisher (with the right permissions)

When in editing mode there is something called "Request Approval"

What does this actually do, and why does it keep raising an error 404

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have moderation enabled:

http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-cms/en/latest/getting_started/configuration.html#cms-moderator

so that every change made by a publisher needs to be approved by the admin. I'm not sure why it would be raising a 404 though

Comment: thanks for the comment, yes we have some content publishers, and we want to moderate the changes made. It's very strange since through the admin it works fine, but when editing from the front-end it just bypasses all those settings...